# Count number of iterations in a for loop

Tags: php

Currently have this.

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
     print $i++;
}
```

and it returns something like this. `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` I want it to return that same format, but replace the initial `0` with a `1` then count forward from there, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe just  by doing this: `$i = 1`

Comment: @HerryPotei That will remove the value of `0` which is not what I want, I want to keep the data which comes with `0` in our loop, only changing the number that's displayed to something different.

Comment: your question is not clear. please show the expected result

Comment: How about `print $i + 1;`?

Comment: You have two post increments in your code ($i++). I'm surprised you say it prints `0,1,2,3....`, because it should print something like `0,2,4,8,...`

Comment: Very interesting use of isset() you have my +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; isset($house[$i-1]); $i++) {
   echo $i;
}
```

Like this?

Answer (score 2):

Write it using pre-increment

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); ) {
     print ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$i + 1` instead of `$i++`

`$i++` is equals to `$i = $i + 1`, and it's not correct way in your case

Answer (score 1):

Try this code !
Replace the i++ with i+1

```
   for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) 
        { 
             print $i + 1 ; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about -

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
    if ($i = 0){
       print 1;}
    else{
       print $i++;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful  You are increasing the count two time  .. one in the for and one in  the print

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) { // first increment add  and the onf a iteration
   print $i++; // second increment
}
```

you should simply

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
   print $i;
}
```

and if you need  start from 1 for count the iteration set $1= 1

```
for ($i = 1; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
   print $i;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
```

To:

```
for ($i = 1; isset($house[$i]) + 1; $i++) {
```

You basically want to start the counter at 1. And the "+ 1 " adds 1 to the ending limit to allow it to reach 9

Comment: That will cause an infinite loop, because isset() + 1 will always be evaluated as true.